# Subpackage for python package

Tags: python, package, packaging

I have written a python module and packaged it, now I am trying to add it to a different package as a submodule, such it gets installed and importable when I try to install the second package. What is the best way to do this? should I simply put the scripts in the second package? Or keep it as a separate package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it as separate package a specify dependency in setup.py using keyword 'requires':

```
setup(
    ...
    requires=['otherpackage'],
)
```

More info is in [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) documentation.